# Array results listed one below each other?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-5

I have to mention from the beginning that i am new in this world, so any help would be more than appreciated!

I have some Bootstrap checkboxes that i want to print (window.print) using jQuery.

The only problem is that the array that i create from the checkboxes, lists the results one after another.

HTML:

```
                  <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" name="type" type="checkbox" value="Question1" id="flexCheckDefault">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault">
                  Question1
                </label>
              </div>
              <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" name="type" type="checkbox" value="Question2" id="flexCheckDefault">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault">
                  Question2
                </label>
              </div>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#results_message").text("The results are:");
$("button").on("click", function () {
 var array = [];
 $("input:checkbox[name=type]:checked").each(function () {
   array.push($(this).val());
 });
 $("#results_after").text(array);
 $('#results_after').printThis();
});
```

CSS:

```
#results_after {
  color: green;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  visibility: hidden;
}

#results_message {
  visibility: hidden;
}

@media print {
  #results_message,
  #results_after {
    visibility: visible;
  }
}
```

Because it's an array, the results are separated by a comma and i want them to be one below each other. I was thinking `<br>` would solve the situation but i dont know how to add it.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is: use `array.join()` to separate the array by a delimiter. I chose `<br />` which meant I needed to use `.html()` rather than `.text()`.

`$("#results_after").html(array.join('<br />')).show()`

The `.show()` is because you were hiding the output divs in the css.

```js
$("#results_message").text("The results are:").show();
$("button").on("click", function() {
  var array = [];
  $("input:checkbox[name=type]:checked").each(function() {
    array.push($(this).val());
  });
  $("#results_after").html(array.join('<br />')).show();
});
```

```css
#results_after {
  color: green;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: none;
}

#results_message {
  display: none;
}

@media print {
  #results_message,
  #results_after {
    visibility: visible;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-check">
  <input class="form-check-input" name="type" type="checkbox" value="Question1" id="flexCheckDefault">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault">
                  Question1
                </label>
</div>
<div class="form-check">
  <input class="form-check-input" name="type" type="checkbox" value="Question2" id="flexCheckDefault">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault">
                  Question2
                </label>
</div>
<hr>
<button>click</button>
<div id='results_message'></div>
<div id='results_after'></div>
```

Comment: It worked like a charm, many thanks! Have a nice evening!